# TSQL Limit System Resource Usage Inline?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, resource-management

I already know that you can set the deadlock_priority to -10 if you want to avoid a longer query from completely locking out other queries.

What I'm looking to do is a bit different.

Is there a way to (inline) specify a limit to the amount of RAM, CPU Usage, and so forth for the current query without changing these values for the rest of the system? (IE a Set MaxCPU 10%, Set MaxRam 2GB...etc)

Comment: AFAIK, Other than degree of parallelism you can't do anything related to hardware